# Outlook 2016 for mac - migrate calendar to new exchange account

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

I'm migrating a user from an old exhange host to a new one.
What I did was export everything from his old exchange account (mail, contacts, calendar, etc) to a .olm-file.
Then I created a new profile, set up the new account, and imported everything back into Outlook.

Buut.. the import didn't put everything back into the new account.
Rather, the import made a new local folder with all the contents from the .olm-file.

For mail and contacs I could drag&drop or copy&paste everything into the new exchange account, but for the calendar I don't know what to do?
Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
So I never figured out a way to do this on mac.
I ended up setting the old exchange account up on a windows machine and exporting the calendar.
Then setting up the new account on the same windows machine and then importing the calendar.

I'd still really like to know if anyone has a better solution that doesn't involve a windows machine.